# CSS to class + anyclass

Tags: html, css

I need to add different styles to an element when it has one specific class and other styles when it has that specific class plus another (not specific)

This is because this second class varies with the page

So far I've tried:

```
.page {display: none;}
.page[class=""] {display: block;}
```

or

```
.page {display: none;}
.page.* {display: block;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.page` (for elements that have a class `page`) and `[class="page"]` (for elements that have only class `page`), but the order of the styles matter:

```css
.page {
  color: blue;
}

[class="page"] {
  color: red;
}

/* order matters */
```

```html
<h1 class="page">PAGE</h1>
<h1 class="page larry">PAGE, LARRY</h1>
```

To see why the order matters, check this:

```css
[class="page"] {
  color: red;
}

.page {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="page">PAGE</h1>
<h1 class="page larry">PAGE, LARRY</h1>
```

`.page` overrides `[class="page"]`.

Answer (score 5):

- Use a *class selector* to require that it has the class you want.
- Use an *attribute selector* to require an exact match for the specific class attribute value (i.e. exactly matches a string).

Note the limitation that attribute selectors are sensitive to whitespace.

Such:

```css
div {
  margin: 1ex;
  padding: 1ex;
  border: dotted 1px #aaa;
}

.foo {
  /* Includes foo */
  background: yellow;
}

[class="foo"] {
  /* Has *only* foo */
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>No class attribute</div>
<div class="">No classes</div>
<div class="foo">Foo</div>
<div class=" foo ">Foo + whitespace</div>
<div class="foo bar">Foo Bar</div>
<div class="foo baz">Foo Baz</div>
```

Note that class and attribute selectors have *equal* specificity so **order matters**.

Answer (score 0):

```
.page {display: none;}
.page + * {display: block;}
```